# Как лучше реализовать сохранение настроек игры/приложения?

Tags: c++

Хочу осуществить сохранение внесённых изменений в настройках игры. То есть, чтобы при последующих запусках программы сохранялись установленные значения с предыдущего запуска.

Например, по-умолчанию громкость звука в игре 100% (отдельная переменная в классе игры, которая при создании объекта инициализируется этим значением - 100), пользователь уменьшает её до 60% и закрывает программу. И нужно чтобы при следующем запуске было 60%. И так же со всеми другими изменениями (параметры экрана, элементы управления и тд).

Но не знаю как лучше это реализовать на С++ - стоит создать отдельный файл (текстовый?), в котором по ключевым словам записывать, а потом считывать установленные по ним значения и инициализировать ими переменные, которые будут аргументами для конфигурации настроек?

Возможно, стоит это как-то сделать с помощью БД, но я в них вообще не разбираюсь и даже не знаю с чего начать.

---

**Какими способами можно осуществить сохранение настроек, да и вообще других данных в программе? И какие лучше всего использовать? Существуют ли паттерны на этот счёт?**

Comment: Вот вы спрашиваете "лучше всего", но при этом не выдвигаете никаких критериев "лучшести", а судя по фразе "не знаю с чего начать" единственным критерием в данном случае будет возможность осилить предложенные способ. Так что начните с просмотра 100500 ранее заданных вопросов про запись / чтение данных и сериализацию.

Comment: Если программа для Windows, то в реестре — он как раз и создан для централизованного хранения конфигурации. По соглашению параметры должны храниться в `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Имя вашей программы` или `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Ваше имя или псевдоним\Имя вашей программы`.

Comment: Зачем бд для настроек? Используйте сохранение настроек в файл, как Вы  и написали.